# Haskell instance dispatch based on constraints

Tags: haskell

I am trying to figure out how to define, within a `class`, functions which will be invoked as appropriate for specific constraints on the data. Because I'm a Haskell newbie I'm not sure if the preceding is expressed in the proper terms, but perhaps it will be more clear with the following example, which is as close as I've gotten this far:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstrainedClassMethods #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

module Test where

class (Eq a) => AssertEqual a where
   assertEqual :: AssertEqual a => a -> a -> Bool


instance AssertEqual String where
    assertEqual a b
        |    a == b = True
        | otherwise = error $ "Oops. " ++ show a ++ " is not equal to " ++ show b


data Foo = Foo Int deriving Eq

instance AssertEqual Foo where
    assertEqual a b
      |    a == b = True
      | otherwise = error "The two Foos are not equal, but I can't show them to you."

instance (Eq a, Show a) => AssertEqual a where
    assertEqual a b
      |    a == b = True
      | otherwise = error $ "The two items are not equal. One is " ++ (show a) ++ " and the other is " ++ (show b)
```

The above compiles (GHC 8.0.2) but when I invoke `assertEqual "hi" "hi"` I get an error complaining about overlapping instances. I understand why the instances are overlapping in this case, and I think I also understand why this is a bad thing, but what I don't know if there is a solution. Or, of course, if what I want is itself a bad idea (and if that is the case, why it is a bad idea.)

Comment: For your case, just turn on `OverlappingInstances` and the right overlap flag (see the GHC users guide on overlapping instances). The more general problem of "functions which will be invoked as appropriate for specific constraints on the data" doesn't have a good solution. The issue is that Haskell resolves instances based on the instance head and _not_ based on the constraints for that head (this is by design, not a bug). See [this wiki page](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/AdvancedOverlap) for more on working around that.

Comment: Thanks! That page will take some digesting, but I'll attack it. Also thanks to your pointer I discovered that in the above I can just add the `OVERLAPPABLE` pragma to the (Eq, Show) instance instead of a file-wide `OverlappingInstances`.

Comment: Ah yes! I keep forgetting that you can use `OVERLAPPABLE` without enabling `OverlappingInstances`. Given that you've now figured this out, you could also add an answer to your own question. :)

Comment: I could but you deserve the points far more than I do, so please feel free!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with overlapping instances in the example can be solved with the addition of the OVERLAPPABLE directive for the final instance therein:

```
instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} (Eq a, Show a) => AssertEqual a where
assertEqual a b
  |    a == b = True
  | otherwise = error $ "The two items are not equal. One is " ++ (show a) ++ " and the other is " ++ (show b)
```

However, as Alec kindly mentioned, the more general question of allowing constraints to dictate function dispatch does not have a good solution at present.